# Highcharts overlapping gauge with legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I have the following problem. On my webside I am working with highcharts, especially with gauge. I have to use the vertical alignment of the legend and the marginleft property in order to save space between the legend and chart, but unfortunately, if I am resizing the website, e.g. make the window smaller, or print the chart, the legend and the chart are overlapping.
The following js fiddle should demonstrate this:

http://jsfiddle.net/7sc70zdn/

```
    legend: {
        allowDecimals:false,
        itemWidth: 240,
        itemStyle:{
            cursor: 'default'
        },
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        layout: 'vertical',
        x: 0,
        y: 100,
        useHTML:true
    },
```

Here is the part, where I think, that the overlapping is occurred. But this property I need
In the jsfiddle the marginleft property can be seen as inappropriate but on the original website, it is very useful. Do you know, how I can prevent this overlapping?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to modify `pane.center` option? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7sc70zdn/2/ - center can have values in pixels or percentage. Or just set `marginLeft` to `180` instead of `-180`. But as you said it may not work for you for some reasons.